# On some endomorphisms of finite groups of odd order.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of odd order.  It is known that if every central automorphism of $G$ acts trivially on the center, then $G$ is purely non-abelian, this amounts to saying that every central endomorphism $u$ of $G$ (an endomorphism such that $x^{-1}u(x) \in Z(G)$, for all $x \in G$) is an automorphism.

I could generalize this (using some ring theory) to the case of the automorphisms acting trivially on a quotient of an abelian normal subgroup: Let $A$ be an abelian normal subgroup of $G$.  If every automorphism of $G$ acting trivially on $G/A$ leaves $A$ element-wise fixed, then every endomorphism of $G$ acting trivially on $G/A$ is an automorphism.

I wonder if one can see a  straightforward purely group theoretic proof of this result.

Have you a counter example, if one replace $A$ by any normal subgroup of $G$?  More precisely, given a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that any automorphism $u$ acting trivially on $G/N$ (that is $x^{-1}u(x) \in N$, for all $x \in G$), leaves $N$ element-wise fixed.  Is it true that every endomorphism $v$ of $G$ such that $x^{-1}v(x) \in N$, for all $x \in G$, is an automorphism?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider asking your question also on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Thank you Professor Andreas.